# Problem with FastAPI patch request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, rest, fetch, fastapi

I made a REST service on python using FastAPI and I need to call the API using Javascript.

This is my FastAPI server:

```
class FieldUpdate(BaseModel):
item_id: Optional[int] = None
field_name: Optional[str] = None
field_value: Optional[str] = None

@router.patch("/update/item", response_model=FieldUpdate)
def update_item(body: FieldUpdate):
    item_id = body.item_id
    field_name = body.field_name
    field_value = body.field_value
    ctx_sle = get my current contenxt
    status = execute method after contenxt initialization (it has nothing to do with running the API)
    return status
```

And in my JS script I tried this request using fetch

```
class FieldUpdate {
  constructor(item_id, field_name, field_value) {
    this.item_id = item_id;
    this.field_name = field_name;
    this.field_value = field_value;
  }

}
async function update_field_from_cell(field) {


const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/scriptlab/update/item";
  try {
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
      body: field
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.text());
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

But every time I run this request, it returns the `422 Unprocessable Entity` error. Do you have any tips to solve this problem?

Comment: did you check the response body? this might include a hint on what failed

Comment: i found 2 issues that block execution of my script, the first one is the bad definition of type of field_value:str in python script and i changed it with field_value:typing.any. And the second issue the bad format of variable that will be send in js script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out earlier, the  *422 Unprocessable Entity* error is thrown when the payload that is received does not match the expected one. Your script sends a JS object, but, instead, should send a JSON String, as shown in the code below. Also, make sure to use the correct url in your request (as I noticed that the one you are using does not match any endpoint in your API). Please remember to change the body attribute to `body: json_data` as well.

```
async function update_field_from_cell(field) {
    var obj = {"item_id": field.item_id, "field_name": field.field_name, "field_value": field.field_value};
    json_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/item";
      try {
        await fetch(url, {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
          body: json_data
        })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.text());
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in fact, I got that wrong and above all I wrongly typed the FieldUpdate class that is in the python code, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The Error code 422 will be thrown if the request payload does not match with the actual payload accepted by your API.

The Pydantic model you use, validates and accepts only the request payload that matches.

Example payload that can be used here:

1)

```
{
  "item_id":1, #integer
  "field_name": "some_name", #string
  "field_value": "some_value" #string
}
```

2. Any of the values can be "null". Because you have mentioned all the fields as optional:

```
{
  "item_id":null, #integer
  "field_name": "some_name", #string
  "field_value": null #string
}
```