# Why does Switching from JQuery AJAX to Fetch cause a 422 Error?

Tags: ajax, fetch, fastapi, jquery-ajax

I'm trying to convert a small FastAPI web app from JQuery AJAX to Fetch API.

The AJAX call sends some JSON to the server which is run through a function on the backend. The original JQuery code looks like this:

```
    static run_task_one(E1, E2, E3, n1, n2, success, error) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/run/task/one",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                E1: E1,
                E2: E2,
                E3: E3,
                n1: n1,
                n2: n2,
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: success,
            error: error,
        });
    }
```

This works fine.

My current implementation using FetchAPI is the following:

```
    static run_task_one(E1, E2, E3, n1, n2, success, error) {
        fetch("/run/task/one", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                E1: E1,
                E2: E2,
                E3: E3,
                n1: n1,
                n2: n2,
            }),
            headers: {
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())

    }
```

This returns a `422` error code, along with the message: `"value is not a valid dict"` in the response. I've checked the response payload for each of the requests and both have the same value:

```
{"E1":"0.92","E2":"1.1","E3":"1.43","n1":"0.0025","n2":"0.0005"}
```

I understand FastAPI uses Pydantic, is it related to this package? Is the input provided by Fetch's `body` parameter different from JQuery's `data` parameter?

Comment: If you look in your browser's development tools and go to the Network tab, you should be able to see the exact difference between the two requests.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've added some extra information to the question, it seems the payload in both cases is exactly the same, is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Verify that the sent content-types are actually identical. Copy each request to a separate document and lay the documents over each other (switch back and forth) and you should be able to spot the difference.

Comment: @MatsLindh When you say copy each request, which part of the network tab should I be copying from? Payload, Headers, etc.?

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669813/17865804).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by me incorrectly defining the `Content-Type` header in the fetch request. I used `contentType` as the request header, which was copied from the JQuery AJAX implementation.

Using this header with Fetch created an extra header type called `contentType`, whilst `Content-Type`, the header I was trying to change, was set to a default value.

[image]

The default value is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, which doesn't match the `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` value I'm trying to use. This meant my data was unreadable by FastAPI on the backend.